# Turn an LED on/off LED with a flip-flop counter

Tags: led, led-matrix, falstad

I want to make a 7x7 LED matrix which begins to turn on the first one LED to the last and then turns off the way back (spiral matrix.)  I'm trying to turn the LEDs on/off by using signal created by flip flop counter.

I have a MOD 15 synchronous counter using JK FFs and at the 9th state (the 7 segment LED display "8") I use the output signal go through the AND gate so I have the high signal and connect to the LED, then the LED turn ons.  Is there any way to keep the LED turn on until I use another high signal to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: Your diagram shows a 7 segment LED, not a 7x7 matrix (which would have 49 separate LEDs)

Comment: Yes, total LEDs is 49, but i will do the same with this one

Comment: To me it is not clear what the question has to do with the LED matrix. Do you want to toggle the LED state every time the counter reaches binary value 8?

Comment: No, the LED always toggle when the "8" state show up, but i want to keep it turn on with the "8" signal until i use another signal to turn its off, but with answer below, i can use shift registers to completed a round of my matrix, and i am trying to make it repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *any help would be greatly appreciated*

I would use an MCU but, if that is not an option then, a string of shift registers, something like this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://hkn.illinois.edu/wiki/wiki:logic_design:registers). The above is a small section that needs repeating to produce outputs for all your LEDs. Shown above are four cascaded D type flip-flops and these would be used with 4 LEDs so, you'll need one per LED.

So with logic high on the input (labelled D3), for each clock pulse, logic high gets shifted along the outputs thus, each LED in your spiral can be illuminated sequentially with the previous ones remaining on.

The problem then comes with turning them off sequentially in reverse order but this can be achieved by a similar circuit operating in reverse. You can engineer a simple logic gate circuit for each LED to disable the previously illuminated LEDs in reverse order: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIq4c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or, you can use the reversing set of flip-flops to raise the LED cathode to 5 volts (logic level 1) to extinguish each LED in turn.

> *I have a MOD 15 synchronous counter using JK FFs*

You probably don't really want to be using counters but, someone else may come up with a cool answer that does.

You did say "any help would be appreciated"!

Comment: First, thank you so much sir, i am very appreciated for you answer, and of course your answer help me a lot, so about the turning the LEDs on is completed, about the turn it off, i will keep think about your solution, but i have to say it again, thank you so much sir.